# Префиксное и постфиксное поведение перегруженных унарных операторов

Tags: c#, перегрузка-операторов

Допустим есть определенный класс, в котором перегружен оператор --, который удаляет случайное значение из HashSet:

```
    class SomeClass<T> where T : IComparable
    {
        private HashSet<T> values;
        private static Random rnd = new Random();

        private SomeClass(IEnumerable<T> value) => this.values = new HashSet<T>(value);
        private SomeClass(HashSet<T> value) => this.values = value;

        public int Lenght
        {
            get
            {
                return values.Count;
            }
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return values.ElementAt(index);
            }
        }

        public SomeClass(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.GetFullPath(path)))
                {
                    values = sr.ReadToEnd()
                        .Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(x => (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T)))
                        .ToHashSet();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ошибка приведения типов");
            }
        }

        public SomeClass(int count, Func<T, T> func)
        {
            T[] arr = new T[count];
            values = arr.Select(func).ToHashSet();
        }

        public static SomeClass<T> operator +(SomeClass<T> hashSetOne, SomeClass<T> hashSetTwo) =>
            new SomeClass<T>(hashSetOne.values.Union(hashSetTwo.values));

        public static SomeClass<T> operator -(SomeClass<T> hashSetOne, SomeClass<T> hashSetTwo) =>
            new SomeClass<T>(hashSetOne.values.Except(hashSetTwo.values));

        public static SomeClass<T> operator *(SomeClass<T> hashSetOne, SomeClass<T> hashSetTwo) =>
            new SomeClass<T>(hashSetOne.values.Intersect(hashSetTwo.values));

        public static SomeClass<T> operator %(SomeClass<T> hashSetOne, int index) =>
            new SomeClass<T>(hashSetOne.values.Where((x, y) => y != index));

        public static SomeClass<T> operator --(SomeClass<T> hashSetOne)
        {
            hashSetOne.values.Remove(hashSetOne.values.ElementAt(rnd.Next(0, hashSetOne.values.Count())));
            return new SomeClass<T>(hashSetOne.values);
        }

        public static bool operator |(SomeClass<T> hashSetOne, T value) =>
            hashSetOne.values.Contains(value);

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string result = "";

            foreach (var item in values)
                result += $"{item} ";

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Однако префиксный и постфиксный вызов данного оператора ведет себя совершенно одинаково:

```
    class Program
    {
        static Random rnd = new Random();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeClass<int> vs1 = new SomeClass<int>(5, x => x = rnd.Next(256));
            Console.WriteLine(vs1);
            Console.WriteLine(vs1--);
            Console.WriteLine(--vs1);
        }
    }
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы разная форма записи данного оператора вела себя по разному?

Comment: 1. Как выводит сейчас? 2. Как должно выводить? У меня в linqpad выдаёт вот так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdBdP.png

Comment: @AK Я думаю, что ТС хочет, чтобы выполнялось условие `vs.equals(vs--) == true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что перед созданием нового объекта `SomeClass`, вы модифицируете `values` в текущем объекте. Этого делать не нужно

```
private SomeClass(HashSet<T> value) => this.values = new HashSet<T>(value);

public static SomeClass<T> operator --(SomeClass<T> hashSetOne)
{
    SomeClass<T> res = new SomeClass<T>(hashSetOne.values);
    res.values.Remove(res.values.ElementAt(rnd.Next(0, res.values.Count())));
    return res;
}
```

Операторы декремента выполняются так

```
SomeClass c1;
SomeClass c2;
c2 = c1--
```

эквивалентно такому коду

```
temp = c1
c1 = operator--(c1)
c2 = temp
```

а

```
с2 = --с1
```

такому

```
temp = operator++(c1)
c1 = temp
c3 = temp
```